# Make GTK/Gnome NOT use the theme's mouse cursor

Tags: gnome, mouse, gtk, theme, cursor

I had to install a GTK/Gnome theme (Adwaita) because some programs wouldn't work without one. But I hate that cursor theme. I prefer the lean look of the default cursor.pcf font.

How can I prevent GTK/Gnome applications from changing the cursor shape to the theme's? I guess deleting `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors` should work, but I'd prefer a less drastic option.

The distribution is Void, if that's any help.

---

**Partial answer** I've found that in the case of GTK 2 applications, it is done by commenting out the line

```
gtk-cursor-theme-name = "Adwaita"
```

in `/usr/share/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on debian, `/etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme` governs which cursor theme is used.  I replaced that file with an empty one and it worked.  It's annoying that many apps require adwaita theme installed...